# Make a phone call programmatically iOS 10 without prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can I make a phone call from my app on iOS 10.3.1 in Objective-C without prompt?

I have tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:xxxxxxxxxxx"]];
```

But get a promt from app like
[image: this]

Comment: Think about it for a minute: would you install an application on your phone that could make a phone call without your intervention? No phone OS is going to let an application do that.

Comment: How can this ever be a good idea for Apple to allow? Excuse me while I make a phone call to my premium number without your consent. Oh, look, we just charged $5 for connecting the call! Yay!...

Comment: I certainly understand. Such an application should not be passed in the appStore. But I'm like a developer, why can not run on my own device. As far as I understand, in earlier versions, I can use 'tel' protocol or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. It's [iOS 10.3 innovation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/)

> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://, facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and requires user confirmation before dialing.

Answer (score 4):

No, [you will always see confirmation Alert](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) before the phone call.

Comment: "When a user opens a URL with the tel scheme in a native app, iOS does not display an alert and initiates dialing without further prompting the user." As I understand from the native app, a call without confirmation is allowed. And if I run the application on iOS 9.3.5 then the call is succes. Just checked. Http://take.ms/mWq4J

Comment: What do you mean by "Native app"?

Comment: Objective-C or Swift app, installed on phone

Comment: iOS 10.3 and later displays an alert and requires user confirmation before dialing